# How can I change the form of HTML/CSS to JSON?

Tags: css, json, html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.collapsible {
background-color: #004c97;
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 18px;
width: 100%;
border: none;
text-align: left;
outline: none;
font-size: 15px;
font-family: Arial;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
background-color: #FFC61E;
}

.content {
padding: 0 18px;
display: none;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
font-family: Arial;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<h1>User_Testing1</h1>
<button class="collapsible">This is the first tab</button>
<div class="content">
<p>This is the sub-category of the first tab.</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">This is the second tab</button>
<div class="content">
<p>This is the sub-category of the second tab.</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">This is the third tab</button>
<div class="content">
<p>This is the sub-category of the third tab.</p>
</div>

<button class="collapsible">This is the fourth tab</button>
<div class="content">
<p>This is the sub-category of the fourth tab,</p>
</div>

<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
this.classList.toggle("active");
var content = this.nextElementSibling;
if (content.style.display === "block") {
content.style.display = "none";
} else {
content.style.display = "block";
}
});
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Hello! I am new to JSON/HTML programming. I created this HTML webpage using HTML/CSS, but I am looking to convert the following code to JSON. I watched several videos on YouTube/Udemy and read several articles on the topic but the only thing I find is creating tables in HTML/JSON. Please help me on this matter. I'd really appreciate your efforts.
Thank you

Comment: For what purpose? HTML and JSON are entirely different things.

Comment: @Blazemonger Publishing it on a webpage.

Comment: HTML is a language designed for describing the content of a webpage. CSS is a language for describing how to display an HTML document (it also works with other languages). JSON is a simple data format for describing arrays, objects, numbers, strings and a few other basic data types. They aren't remotely interchangeable. There is no standard way to express HTML or CSS in JSON. If you were to store your data in JSON, you would have to convert it back to HTML and CSS before it could be rendered in a webpage. Your question needs a lot more context to make sense.

Comment: @Quentin Following up with your suggestion, how do I store data into JSON simultaneously working along HTML and CSS so that I don't lose my formatting and content?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing concepts. As others have pointed out, JSON is just another way in which you can represent information in a way that both humans and machines can easily understand. It is a format.

Could you convert your HTML page into JSON? The simple answer is yes, but there would be no benefit in doing so.

```js
var json = {
  html: '<h1>User_Testing1</h1> <button class="collapsible">This is the first tab</button> <div class="content"> <p>This is the sub-category of the first tab.</p> </div> <button class="collapsible">This is the second tab</button> <div class="content"> <p>This is the sub-category of the second tab.</p> </div> <button class="collapsible">This is the third tab</button> <div class="content"> <p>This is the sub-category of the third tab.</p> </div> <button class="collapsible">This is the fourth tab</button> <div class="content"> <p>This is the sub-category of the fourth tab,</p> </div>',
  css: '.collapsible { background-color: #004c97; color: white; cursor: pointer; padding: 18px; width: 100%; border: none; text-align: left; outline: none; font-size: 15px; font-family: Arial; } .active, .collapsible:hover { background-color: #FFC61E; } .content { padding: 0 18px; display: none; overflow: hidden; background-color: #f1f1f1; font-family: Arial; }',
  javascript: 'var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible"); var i; for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) { coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() { this.classList.toggle("active"); var content = this.nextElementSibling; if (content.style.display === "block") { content.style.display = "none"; } else { content.style.display = "block"; } }); }'
};

var page = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">' + '<style>' + json.css + '</style>' + '</head><body>' + json.html + '<script>' + json.javascript + '<\/script>' + '</body></html>';

document.write(page);
document.close()
```

Comment: A note: `document.write(....);` always needs to be followed by `document.close();` or else it may not display properly in some browsers.

Comment: @PeterB Modified my answer to include that. Thank you for catching that.